# Passing through multiple ids on jQuery function

Tags: jquery

How do you pass through multiple elements on a jQuery function?

This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="hello">This is the default text</textarea>
<input id="hello2" value="This is another text box">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
    $('#hello', '#hello2').each(function() {
        $.data(this, 'default', this.value);
    }).focus(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
            this.value = "";
        }
    }).change(function() {
        $.data(this, 'edited', this.value != "");
    }).blur(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, 'edited')) {
            this.value = $.data(this, 'default');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eJP9C/252/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('#hello', '#hello2')
```

Use

```
$('#hello, #hello2')
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eJP9C/253/)